# any live examples of ecommerce for fast food restaurants developed in Magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-2-commerce

Are there any live examples of the websites in the fast food industry which are developed in Magento ? I am looking forward to search the websites but i didn't find any website in fast food industry in any country which are developed in Magento. Secondly i have also noticed that the modern fast food industry require different business processes (i-e you have to select store and type of service like self collect or delivery before you add item to the cart etc or have to restrict adding item to the cart after the store operational hours) which out of the box are not supported in Magento.

So any live examples of the fast food restaurants in Magento will be highly appreciated.